# I am using asp.net MVC 1.0 and want to apply some jquery or javascript in below code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"        Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ens.ContactPerson>" %>

      <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
          Edit
      </asp:Content>

         <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

            <h2>Edit</h2>
            <%if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {  %>
            <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Edit was unsuccessful                         . Please correct           the                   errors and try again.")%>

<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <%= Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Id", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="FirstName">FirstName:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("FirstName", Model.FirstName)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="MiddleName">MiddleName:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("MiddleName", Model.MiddleName)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("MiddleName", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="LastName">LastName:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("LastName", Model.LastName)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("LastName", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="DateOfBirth">DateOfBirth:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("DateOfBirth", String.Format("{0:g}", Model.DateOfBirth))%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("DateOfBirth", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="ContactPersonType">ContactPersonType:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("ContactPersonType")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("ContactPersonType", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%=Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "All")%>
    </div>
<%} %>
</asp:Content>
```

can i apply some javascript or jquery here such that after click on submit button, it must checks for the values are valid , if can do so.

pls give code for the validation of last name field...this should not be empty.

i tried with this function but it dindt work....

```
    protected void ValidateContact(ens.ContactPerson contactToValidate)
    {
        if (contactToValidate.FirstName.Trim().Length == 0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", "First name is required.");
        if (contactToValidate.LastName.Trim().Length == 0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("LastName", "Last name is required.");
        if (contactToValidate.MiddleName.Trim().Length == 0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("MiddleName", "Invalid phone number.");
        if (contactToValidate.DateOfBirth.ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Invalid email address.");
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did't work? Show us some of your own effort before asking for teh codez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, You can force validate entire form with `Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm`. Example: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/11/asp-net-mvc-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents.aspx

You will need some JavaScript references. Follow this http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/02/validating-hidden-fields-in-asp-net-mvc-2/

After that, you can just call any javascript method on submit button, do javascript validation and then submit the form.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ValidateLastName(name) {

       //all validation here

        var form = document.forms[0];
        form.action = '/AddressType/Create';
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

OR may be one of these may help,

http://forums.asp.net/t/1538157.aspx/1

[My Own javascript validation + MicrosoftMvcValidation . Is it possible ? How](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314158/my-own-javascript-validation-microsoftmvcvalidation-is-it-possible-how)

Comment: Doesn't Html.EnableClientValidation() require MVC2?  He's using 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to make the submit button a regular button and onclick call a javascript function that validates your fields.  If the validation passes you can submit the form with $("#myForm").submit().  You can do something like var lastName = $("#LastName").val() to get the value in your last name textbox and then test the value in lastName.